# Hive UDF to process array of integers in Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, udf

I'm newbie in scala and I need to write user-defined function for processing columns with array of integers in Hive (type `array<int>`).

I've tried:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF

class testUDF extends UDF {

  def evaluate(arr: Array[Int], txt: String): Boolean = {
    return false
  }

}
```

But when I tried to call it in SQL I got error:

```
No matching method for class ... with (array<int>, string). Possible choices: _FUNC_(struct<>, string)
```

What type I need to use in Scala to work with array columns in Hive?

Comment: you will need to use hadoop datatypes (`writable`) - http://hadooptutorial.info/hadoop-data-types/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found specific class to that cases:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF;
```